# jQuery scrollTop a little jumpy

Tags: jquery, scroll, scrolltop

I am building a site with vertical scroll.

I have implemented the jquery below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("document").ready(function() {            

            $('.homebutton').click(function(){

                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $("#home").offset().top
                }, 1500);                  


             });



            $('.aboutbutton').click(function(){

                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $("#about").offset().top
                }, 1500);                  


             });


            $('.portfoliobutton').click(function(){

                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $("#portfolio").offset().top
                }, 1500);                  


             });



            $('.contactbutton').click(function(){

                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $("#contact").offset().top
                }, 1500);                  


             });

});
</script>
```

With the following HTML :

```
<div id="wrapper">

<div id="home" class="tab home">

    <div class="header">

        <div class="logo">

            <img src="images/logo.jpg" />

        </div>

        <div class="menuholder">

            <ul id="homemenu" class="menu">

                <li><a class="active homebutton" href="#home">HOME<br /></a>   </li>
                <li><a class="aboutbutton" href="#about">ABOUT<br /></a>   </li>
                <li><a class="portfoliobutton" href="#portfolio">PORTFOLIO<br /></a>   </li>
                <li><a class="contactbutton" href="#contact">CONTACT<br /></a>   </li>

            </ul>

        </div>

        <div class="clr"></div>

    </div>

    <div class="content">

    </div>

</div>

<div id="about" class="tab">

    <div class="header">

        <div class="logo">

            <img src="images/logo.jpg" />

        </div>

        <div class="menuholder">

            <ul id="aboutmenu" class="menu">

                <li><a href="#home" class="homebutton">HOME</a>   </li>
                <li><a class="active aboutbutton" href="#about">ABOUT<br /><span>All you need to know</span></a>   </li>
                <li><a href="#portfolio" class="portfoliobutton">PORTFOLIO<br /><span>See what we can do!</span></a>   </li>
                <li><a href="#contact" class="contactbutton">CONTACT<br /><span>Get in touch and say HI!</span></a>   </li>

            </ul>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="content">

    </div>

</div>

<div id="portfolio" class="tab">

    <div class="header">

        <div class="logo">

            <img src="images/logo.jpg" />

        </div>

        <div class="menuholder">

            <ul id="portfoliomenu" class="menu">

                <li><a href="#home" class="homebutton">HOME</a>   </li>
                <li><a href="#about" class="aboutbutton">ABOUT<br /><span>All you need to know</span></a>   </li>
                <li><a class="active portfoliobutton" href="#portfolio">PORTFOLIO<br /><span>See what we can do!</span></a>   </li>
                <li><a href="#contact" class="contactbutton">CONTACT<br /><span>Get in touch and say HI!</span></a>   </li>

            </ul>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="content">

    </div>

</div>

<div id="contact" class="tab">

    <div class="header">

        <div class="logo">

            <img src="images/logo.jpg" />

        </div>

        <div class="menuholder">

            <ul id="contactmenu" class="menu">

                <li><a href="#home" class="homebutton">HOME</a>   </li>
                <li><a href="#about" class="aboutbutton">ABOUT<br /><span>All you need to know</span></a>   </li>
                <li><a href="#portfolio" class="portfoliobutton">PORTFOLIO<br /><span>See what we can do!</span></a>   </li>
                <li><a class="active contactbutton" href="#contact">CONTACT<br /><span>Get in touch and say HI!</span></a>   </li>

            </ul>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="content">

    </div>

</div>

</div>
```

My problem is that the scroll can be a little jumpy when jumping between the Home and Contact links. Admittedly it only does this when you click on one of the buttons before the scroll has had time to catch its breath, but this particular client is very specific with how things work, and I know they will pick up on it (plus I would never knowingly want to release something with a bug, however minor).

My question is, is there an easy way to queue the actions in jQuery so the previous action has time to stop and catch its breath before the next one starts?

I have tried .stop() after the click function, and after the animate function. The one after the click function made it worse, and the one after the animate function broke it all together...

Many thanks in advance!

Kevin

Comment: Wow! I thought I had accepted those answers, but instead I had been voting them up! All fixed now...

Thank you for your response, I have tried that and alas, no joy. Am I safe to post links here?

Comment: Of course - links to example code are encouraged.

Comment: In fact it does effect it, it seems to almost reverse the problem. It doesn't seem to jumpy if you hit the next button quickly, but if you leave it for a few seconds it appears to jump when you click. I am not sure as my eyes aren't great but I think it is jumping to the top of the page first, then carrying on as it should...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('.homebutton').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); //This will stop the jumping
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#home").offset().top
    }, 1500);                  
});
```

Also, as an added bonus, how about making it all one function instead of having one function for each menu item? Something like:

```
$("#homemenu a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var section = $(this).attr("href");
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: $(section).offset().top  
    }, 1500);   
});
```

Comment: @KevinSmith - also check the edit. It'll help you minimize your code a bit.

Comment: Perfect! I just applied the tidy up (I targetted .menu a instead as the menu repeats in each section) and all works great. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you have.

```
$('.homebutton').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#home").offset().top
    }, 1500);                  
});
```

If you put return false, that will do the trick. It too prevents the default action.

```
$('.homebutton').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#home").offset().top
    }, 1500);

    return false;                  
});
```

Also you may want to look into refactoring down the line to handle these click events that scroll to particular points.

ex:

```
$('traverse to menu anchor').on('click', function() {
    var target = $(this).attr('href');

    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(target).offset().top }, 1000 );
        return false;
});
```

Hope this helps.